# Configure Firebase Authentication to send INVALID_CREDENTIALS instead of EMAIL_NOT_FOUND or INVALID_PASSWORD

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using free Firebase plan for testing my React apps and I'm working on authentication with email and password provider right now.

I'm using Firebase straight in my client.

I managed to handle authentication errors in UI and show users a message like `Invalid credentials` if either their email or password is wrong but I still get `EMAIL_NOT_FOUND` or `INVALID_PASSWORD` response from firebase in the network tab.

This is how I'm handling the UI

```js
try {
  setFirebaseError("");
  await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password);
} catch (err) {
  if (["auth/wrong-password", "auth/user-not-found"].includes(err.code)) setFirebaseError("Invalid credentials");
  else setFirebaseError(err.message);
}
```

But the response is either

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I don't want that.

Is there a way to configure Firebase Authenticaton to send custom error response?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to send custom error responses specifically, or are you just trying to prevent your application leaking information about whether the login failed due to EMAIL_NOT_FOUND vs. INVALID_PASSWORD?  There's a setting in GCP called "email enumeration protection" which does the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: "your_given_email",
  password: "your_given_password!"
);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            if (e.code == 'network-request-failed') {
              showErrorDialog(context, 'No Internet Connection');
              //devtools.log('No Internet Connection');
            } else if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
              return showErrorDialog(
                  context, 'Please Enter correct password');
              //devtools.log('Please Enter correct password');
              //print('Please Enter correct password');
            } else if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
              showErrorDialog(context, 'Email not found');
              // print('Email not found');
            }  else if (e.code == 'too-many-requests') {
              return showErrorDialog(
                  context, 'Too many attempts please try later');
              //print('Too many attempts please try later');
            } else if (e.code == 'unknwon') {
              showErrorDialog(
                  context, 'Email and password field are required');
              //print('Email and password field are required');
            } else if (e.code == 'unknown') {
              showErrorDialog(
                  context, 'Email and Password Fields are required');
              //print(e.code);
            } else {
              print(e.code);
            }
          }
```

Comment: I already did this, I'm talking about the response I get in the network tab, that's what I want to change

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue, ensure you have Email Enumeration protection enabled. See here for more details:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#enable